# OpenCL support for both Intel CPU and Nvidia GPU

Tags: linux, opencl

When querying for supported OpenCL platforms/devices, my Nvidia GPU gets returned, thanks to the OpenCL runtime provided by the CUDA SDK.

However, the Intel Xeon CPU does not.

I see that Intel provides an [OpenCL Runtime](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/opencl-drivers.html) for its CPUs. However, it seems to require replacing libOpenCL.so.

With some linker hackery I was able to get the Intel runtime loaded into my process but then **only** the Intel CPU, not the Nvidia device, is enumerated.

Is there a way to get them to co-exist so I can distribute tasks across both the GPU and CPU?

Comment: Maybe create a process for each? You could then use shared memory for inter-process communication.

Comment: What ICD loader are you linking? The one that came with the SDK I assume, have you tried Khronos ICD loader? https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader. I don't understand why the Nvidia one wouldn't work though, are both vendors visible in /etc/OpenCL/vendors?

Comment: @FA-18_1 I don't have access to install a new ICD file. I tried the environment variable to search another directory but it didn't work. I have tried using `LD_PRELOAD` to load both Nvidia and Intel libraries but that didn't work either (Intel won).

Comment: What about using OCL_ICD_VENDORS for selecting vendors? You could probably apply LD_LIBRARY_PATH to use the Khronos ICD.